# Call method if optional parameter in't null in c#

Tags: c#

I have a method with two optional parameters. I want to shorten my code.
here is my code:

```
DataTable dtList;
if (!duration.ContainsKey("startDay") && duration.ContainsKey("endDay"))
{
    dtList = GetAllReservation();
}
else if (duration.ContainsKey("startDay") && !duration.ContainsKey("endDay"))
{
    dtList = GetAllReservation(duration["startDay"]);
}
else
{
    dtList = GetAllReservation(duration["startDay"], duration["endDay"]);
}
```

is there any way to shorten this code to something like this:

```
dtList = GetAllReservation(duration["startDay"], duration?["endDay"]);
```

this is my method GetAllReservation:

```
public static DataTable GetAllReservation(string start = "1397/01/01", string end = "1400/12/29") =>
    DataAccess.Select($"Exec ReservationList '{start}', '{end}'", ref _methodState);
```

Comment: Your shortened code is missing the `ContainsKey` check, and therefore will throw if key is not found.

Comment: can you show me the signature of `GetAllReservation` method?

Comment: Maybe a default value of 'null' for the params and the ?? operator in the SQL string to supply the real defaults?

Comment: @CoolBots Do you really think your edit made this post more readable? And what is `Data Table`?

Comment: @SeM the original message had no code formatting or syntax highlighting at all; so yes, my edit did make it more readable. My apologies for the "Data Table", phone autocorrect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not define the parameter default to be the business default. Define the parameter default to be null, which signifies a lack of value. The method itself should check for the parameter default and substitute the business default as needed.

```
public static DataTable GetAllReservation(string start = null, string end = null) 
{
    if (start == null) start = _config.GetDefaultStartDate();
    if (end == null) end = _config.GetDefaultEndDate();

    DataAccess.Select($"Exec ReservationList '{start}', '{end}'", ref _methodState);
}
```

Also, you can write an extension method on Dictionary:

```
public static string GetStringOrNull(this Dictionary<string,string> source, string key)
{
    if (!source.ContainsKey(key)) return null;
    return source[key];
}
```

Which allows you to shorten your call to this:

```
GetAllReservation(duration.GetStringOrNull("startDay"), duration.GetStringOrNull("endDay"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
string stDate = duration.ContainsKey("startDay") ? duration("startDay") : null;
string edDate = duration.ContainsKey("endDay") ? duration("endDay") : null;

dtList = GetAllReservation(stDate ,edDate );


public static DataTable GetAllReservation(string start = null, string end = null) 
{
    if (start == null) start = ""; //Set default value
    if (end == null) end = "";//Set default value

    //..... further code
}
```

Comment: This code will pass `null` instead of using the optional parameter if the key is missing

Comment: sorry I forgot to add updated "GetAllReservation" method .. now update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
 dtList = GetAllReservation(duration.ContainsKey("startDay")?duration["startDay"]:"1397/01/01",duration.ContainsKey("endDay")?duration["endDay"]:"1400/12/29");
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of optional parameters here (if you really want shorter version of your code and may be more readable):

```
string startDayDuration = duration.ContainsKey("startDay") ? duration["startDay"] : "1397/01/01";
string endDayDuration = duration.ContainsKey("endDay") ? duration["endDay"] : "1400/12/29";

dtList = GetAllReservation(startDayDuration, endDayDuration);
```

then your method:

```
public static DataTable GetAllReservation(string start, string end) =>
    DataAccess.Select($"Exec ReservationList '{start}', '{end}'", ref _methodState);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, good programming does not necessarily means shorter code. It may be of value to think of each case as a separate method. If each method has a specific function, the logic of each method becomes simpler. It also reduces coding errors and possible exceptions.
In this case you have 3 methods. Each method does a slightly different job depending on the number of parameters, but at the end the return the same sort of result. This looks like a good case of *method overloading*. I believe that method overloading is good as long as the method(s) really do the same core function only with different parameters. Some think that method overloading is Evil.